# String was not declared in this scope in Rcpp

Tags: c, r, rcpp

I am learning to use Rcpp via Hadley's tutorial [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Rcpp). However, when I make the following codes into a .cpp file called `scalar_missing.cpp`

```
# include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List scalar_missings() {
  int int_s = NA_INTEGER;
  String chr_s = NA_STRING;
  bool lgl_s = NA_LOGICAL;
  double num_s = NA_REAL;

  return List::create(int_s, chr_s, lgl_s, num_s);
}

/*** R
  str(scalar_missings())
*/
```

and then in R, I use `sourceCpp("scalar_missing.cpp")` to run, I got the following error:

```
'String was not declared in this scope'
```

What went wrong? My `sessionInfo` is

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.10.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the released notes, the `Rcpp::String` class was added in Rcpp 0.10.2.

You may need to get Hadley to clarify what is needed, and where to get it from, for his tutorial.

Comment: Thank you Dirk -- I upgraded to Rcpp 0.10.2 and it works perfectly now